# Android market filtering: Require dialer?

Tags: android, android-market-filtering

I have made an app for a mobile network that calls a shortcode to find the info.

Some people use 3G tablets that do not have dialers, so the receive a force close error when they press the button.

Is there a market filter to require a dialer?

Telephony is already required, but it doesn't stop it because the 3G is counted as telephony.

Thanks,

Liam

Comment: try this <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony.CALL_PHONE" android:required="true" />

Comment: @TaylorBioniks: You cannot simply invent new feature strings.

Comment: @CommonsWare I got that from the API docs.

Comment: @TaylorBioniks: Do you have a link to the docs showing where you read this? A Google search for `"android.hardware.telephony.CALL_PHONE"` turns up precisely one page: the page that you are reading. I suspect that you misinterpreted something. :-)

Comment: @CommonsWare here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html under <uses-feature>

Comment: Hey @CommonsWare I was wondering if you know how to use auto focus on that camera code you have on github?

Comment: @TaylorBioniks: `CALL_PHONE` is a permission, not a feature string, and as listed as such in that table. With respect to auto-focus, I would assume you use `getSupportedFocusModes()` and `setFocusMode()`, along the lines of how the example uses `getSupportedPreviewSizes()` and `setPreviewSize()`. If you have further questions on that, open up a fresh SO question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a market filter to require a dialer?

No, sorry.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this. I will just have to warn them in the description :)